Landau-Zener system with large complex parameter
The differential equations describing the Landau-Zener system are given by:
$\ddot{d}_{1} + (\frac{t^{2}}{4}+\frac{i}{2} + z)d_{1} = 0 \\
\ddot{d}_{2} + (\frac{t^{2}}{4}-\frac{i}{2} + z)d_{2} = 0 
$
\
where z is called the adiabaticity parameter. They have solutions given in terms of parabolic cylinder functions:
$ d_{1}(t) = c_{1}D_{-iz}(e^{i\pi/4}t) + c_{2} D_{iz-1}(e^{3 i \pi/4}t) \\
d_{2}(t) =e^{i \pi/4} \left( c_{2}D_{iz}(e^{3 i\pi/4}t)/\sqrt{z} + \sqrt{z} c_{1} D_{-iz-1}(e^{ i \pi/4}t) \right)
 $\
The initial condition is $|d_{1}(t \rightarrow -\infty)|^{2} = 1$ and using the asymptotic values of the parbolic cylinder functions:
$D_{-iz}(e^{i \pi/4}t) \rightarrow e^{-it^2/4}t^{-iz}e^{\pi z/4} + e^{it^{2}/4}e^{-5\pi z/4}t^{iz-1} e^{3 i \pi/4} \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{\Gamma(iz)} \\
D_{iz-1} (e^{3 i \pi /4} t) \rightarrow -e^{i \pi/4} e^{i t^{2}/4} t^{iz-1} e^{-3 \pi z/4}
 $ \
we determine that $c_{1} = e^{3 \pi z/4}$ and $c_{2} = \sqrt{2 \pi} i e^{\pi z/4}/\Gamma(iz) $
You can see that for z=5, we get the expected behavior of population transfer.
z=5
However, if I increase z up to 9, I start seeing oscillations and wiggles
z=9
The problem is exacerbated if I increase z to z=11
z=11
My thinking is that they asymptotic behaviors of the parabolic cylinder functions that I have used break down as z increases, but I have not been able to find the correct behaviour anywhere. Has anyone encountered something like this before or does anyone have thoughts on how to solve it?
